# SOAP WCF Webservice behaves differently when called locally or remotely

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I have a WCF SOAP 1.1 Webservice with the configuration specified below.

A concurrent call to any method of this endpoint hangs until the other returns when called remotely (from another computer on the network).

I cannot replicate this when these methods are called locally (with a client located on the same machine).

I tried to increase the maxConcurrentCalls with no luck ... the service behavior seems to be different according to the client local/remote location. Any guess?

When looking at the ServiceModelEndpoint performance counters of a concurrent calls scenario, the results are interesting: remote "calls outstanding" reaches the limit of 2 calls ... whereas local calls of 20 concurrent threads goes up to 18 "calls outstanding"!
The limitation of 2 "remote" calls seems to be "per process".

Thanks,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyCustomBehavior" name="CONTOSO.CONTOSOServerApi.IContosoServiceApiImplV1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebBinding"
          bindingNamespace="http://contoso.com" contract="CONTOSO.CONTOSOServerApiInterfaceV1.IContosoServiceApiV1" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyCustomBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://localhost:8080/MyEndPointV1" />
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="10000" maxConcurrentCalls="1000"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="WebBinding">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" maxReadPoolSize="2147483647" maxWritePoolSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What do you host it in? If you are on a client machine (XP, Vista, 7) and hosting in IIS you will run into some connection issues.

Comment: It is self-hosted with the ServiceHost. Server is under Windows Server 2008 and Client is XP/Win7.

Comment: I tried to connect remotely to the same service hosted on Win7, same problem. Also tried with no firewall and no antivirus... same issue. It seems to be related to WCF.

Comment: I assume that you have tested that the calls are not hanging in your code implementation? Have you tried fiddling with the maxWorkerThreads / minWorkerThreads in machine.config ?


.............
<processModel autoConfig="false" maxWorkerThreads="250" maxIoThreads="250" minWorkerThreads=”4”/>

Comment: Also it is very important that you close and dispose the client connections correctly, else they will just hang around and you will see this behavior - however that will be apparent on the localhost as well.

Comment: When looking at the ServiceModelEndpoint performance counters of a concurrent calls scenario, the results are interesting: remote "calls outstanding" reaches the limit of 2 calls ... whereas local calls of 20 concurrent threads goes up to 18 "calls outstanding"!

Comment: The limitation of 2 "remote" calls seems to be "per process".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is was a client issue, System.Net controls how many outbound TCP connections are used by HttpWebRequest default is 2 per endpoint:

`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;`